# C# - Validación del texto de un TextBox para no eliminar datos

Tags: c#, windows-forms

Tengo datos en una tabla llamada `clientes` en una base de datos en *SQL Server*, el cual lo selecciono desde un `DataGridView` para luego cargar la información a un formulario. Tengo un botón para eliminar al cliente de acuerdo al `ID` que haya seleccionado en el `DataGridView`.

Dentro de la tabla `cliente` tengo una columna llamada `Salda`, la cual va cambiando de acuerdo a otras transacciones que la afecten.

Necesito que, cuando quiera eliminar ese cliente no me lo permita si `Salda` es mayor a cero, de lo contrario, que me deje eliminarlo.

Comment: deberías agregar tu código a la pregunta.

Answer (score 2):

Esto te funcionaría:

```
//Pásalo a valor tipo double de ser necesario.
double Saldo = (Valor del campo "Salda" de tu consulta);

if(Saldo>0)
{
    //mensaje de error del saldo pasado
}
else
{
    //código para eliminar saldo
}
```

Comment: si te sirve, agredecería que marques esta respuesta como la respuesta a tu problema.

Answer (score 0):

Puedes tomar el valor del `TextBox` del formulario y convertirlo a `Double`:

```
Double Saldo = Convert.ToDouble(textBoxObj.Text);
```

Después, si el saldo es positivo,

```
if(Saldo>0){
    //mensaje de error de saldo positivo
}
else{
    //código para eliminar el cliente
}
```